# Can i manipulate the same element of every object of a class?

Tags: c++

e.g:

```
 int main()
    {
       class exampleClass{
       public:
        int x;
                    };

    exampleClass one;
    exampleClass two;
    exampleClass three;

    if (exampleClass manipulate_all x == 5)
    {
      // do something
    }

    return 0;
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
int main()
{
   class exampleClass{
   public:
    int x;
                };

exampleClass one;
exampleClass two;
exampleClass three;

if (one.x == 5)||(two.x == 5)||(three.x == 5)
{
  // do something
}

return 0;
}
```

Very new to c++, so apologies if this is a stupid question, or if this is far too advanced for a beginner.

I'm trying to create a collision system for my game, where each sprite has a class object, so I can check the player object against every other sprite. If this is a terrible idea please tell me.

Comment: short answer: no

Comment: ughhhhhhhhhhh thanks

Comment: Could you explain what your use case is for this? I cant really think of one (at least not one that isn't covered by static member variables)

Comment: Well, technically there is a way, it's just slow, inefficient, and really only useful if you're creating a runtime.

Comment: Should all instances of the class always share the same value? Then a static member variable may be what you want.

Comment: @Borgleader I'm trying to make collision system in my game - yes I know there are much better ways of doing it.

Comment: @John No, they shouldn't

Comment: @baguettio That doesn't really tell me why you need to change all members of a class to one value though. If you could explain what youre trying to achieve / what problem youre trying to solve in more detail maybe we can answer the question more specifically and offer alternatives (would surely be more useful than the lorem ipsum you added in your question to satisfy the length limit...)

Comment: @Borgleader  I have edited the original post.

Comment: How does setting a common variable across all objects of a single class help you check for collision?

Comment: @John It wouldn't be setting a single common variable, I will edit the original post to be more clear.

Comment: That's not clearer. Your example still shows that you want to modify the values to all be 5. Do you want to compare the values to 5 instead?

Comment: @John yeah sorry

Comment: Oooookay. Yeah, common beginner mistake totally understandable. Some of the answers below touch on this. You want your "player" to check if it has collided with anything? Are you writing your own engine or using a preexisting engine?

Comment: @John I'm using a framework

Comment: Which framework? It likely already has a way to access the container of all instances of a type, which is what you need to be able to iterate over.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208774/discussion-between-baguettio-and-john).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have all members share a variable, you can use [static variables](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_static_members.htm)

If they're part of a collision system you probably need a larger structure to hold all of the variables and just use a loop over that.

Alternatively, you could have a static variable as a list keep track of all other members of the class and loop over this, where the static variable is a vector of pointers to instantiated objects. This requires a lot more overhead for the individual class and its own function to modify all of the values.

Either way you'd have to write the container to hold all the values, but it's up to you on how you want to design it.

Modifying your class:

```
class exampleClass{

private:
    static vector<exampleClass*> instances;    
public:
   exampleClass(){ instances.push_back(this);}
   ~exampleClass(){ /*Use some kind of id to find and erase the current instance from the list here.*/}
   int x;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, if your member is a static member, but not if it's an instance member, like your case. But you also need to initialize a static member outside the class.

```
#include<iostream>

class exampleClass
{
    public:
    static int x;
};

int exampleClass::x = 0;


int main()
{
    exampleClass one;
    exampleClass two;
    exampleClass three;

    exampleClass::x = 5;

    std::cout << one.x << two.x << three.x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```